# PDO inserção de dados, não funciona?

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentado criar uma página de cadastro com o PDO porém, ele não realiza a inserção e não apresenta erro, o que pode ser?

```
include "../pages/sqlconn.php";

$name  = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass  = $_POST["password"];

try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO db_user(user_name, user_email, user_pass) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $ins = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $ins->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $ins->bindParam(2, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $ins->bindParam(3, $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $ins->execute();
    echo $ins->execute();       
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Dá um `var_dump($e);` e posta aqui.

Comment: A página deu branco ainda, não retornou nenhum resultado...

Comment: Oras, então ele não está entrando no exception, dê um `var_dump($ins->execute());` e poste aqui.

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\MySQLi-Learn\action\createAccount.php:25:boolean false

Comment: No lugar de `echo $ins->execute()`, coloque `print_r($conn->errorInfo());`

Comment: Retornou um, Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: igor, substitua o VALUES (?,?,?) por  VALUES (:name, :email, :pass) e ao invés de 1, 2 e 3, no bindParam, substitua por :name, :email e :pass em sua devida ordem e veja se apresenta erro.

Comment: Adicione `$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` logo após criar o objeto `$conn` que provavelmente aparecerá a mensagem de erro. Eu testei o código aqui e funcionou perfeitamente. O nome da tabela é `db_user` mesmo ou seria `db_users`?

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss, é isso mesmo mano, eles retornou que estava faltando uma coluna para ter inserção, ai eu defini ela no banco de dados como NULL, agora funcional ele inseriu corretamente.

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim:

```
include "../pages/sqlconn.php";

$name  = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass  = $_POST["password"];

try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO db_user (user_name, user_email, user_pass) VALUES ('$name','$email','$pass')";
    $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll();       
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean

Comment: @IgorDonizete poste o código do `sqlconn.php` por gentileza.

Comment: `<?php

define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "root");
define("PASS", "");
define("DB", "db_teste");

try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DB, USER ,PASS);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
}`